# How to keep selected values for multiselect dropdown after Model state failed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I keep multiselected dropdown values selected if model state failed.

My view Get Action

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult ContainerList()
{
 List<LoginModel> dropdownList= new List<LoginModel>();
 dropdownList= gateway.SelectDropdown();  //Getting values fordropdown
 ViewBag.DropdownList = dropdownList;
}
```

My View

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" required="" asp-for="CategoryID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.DropdownList ,"DropdownID","DropdownName"))" multiple data-live-search="true"
                                                    placeholder="Select Categories"
                                                    onchange="console.log($(this).children(':selected').length)">
 </select>
 </div>
```

My Post Method on controller

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult PasswordVerification(LoginModel loginModel)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    
  }
  else
  {
  }
   List<LoginModel> dropdownList= new List<LoginModel>();
   dropdownList= gateway.SelectDropdown();  //Getting values from dropdown
   ViewBag.DropdownList = dropdownList;
   return View(loginModel);
}
```

How can I can keep selected values . I can do that for single selected dropdown like this

```
ViewBag.city = new SelectList(cityList, "CityID", "CityName", loginModel.CityID);
```

Edited:  Login model

```
Int64 DropdownID {get;set;}
string DropdownName{get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could receive the value of selected item in controller,you could  Set the Selected property of the SelectListItem which shares the same value as true

```
var selectlist = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "text1", Value = "Value1" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "text2", Value = "Value2" } };
selectlist.ForEach(x => { if (x.Value == someEntity.SelectValue) { x.Selected = true; } });
ViewBag.Dropdown = selectlist;
```

Result:

[image]

Update:

generate the list of selectlistitem

```
ViewBag.city  = cityList.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.CityName, Value = x.CityID }).ToList();
```

and in your loginmodel ,you have to add the property：`CategoryID` in it to bind with the selected value

**12/16**

I tried With two methods as below,Hopes could help

Controller:

```
public IActionResult DropDown()
        {
            var citylist = new List<City>() { new City() { CityId = 1, CityName = "City1" }, new City() { CityId = 2, CityName = "City2" }, new City() { CityId = 3, CityName = "City3" } };
            ViewBag.City1 = new SelectList(citylist, "CityId", "CityName");

            ViewBag.City2 = citylist.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.CityName, Value = x.CityId.ToString() }).ToList();
            
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DropDown(SomeViewModel vm)
        {

            var citylist = new List<City>() { new City() { CityId = 1, CityName = "City1" }, new City() { CityId = 2, CityName = "City2" }, new City() { CityId = 3, CityName = "City3" } };
            ViewBag.City1 = new SelectList(citylist, "CityId", "CityName",vm.SelectedId1);

            ViewBag.City2 = citylist.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.CityName, Value = x.CityId.ToString(), Selected = vm.SelectedId2.Contains(x.CityId) }).ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

Model:

```
public class City
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }

        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }


    public class SomeViewModel
    {
        //Bind with the first select list
        public List<int> SelectedId1 { get; set; }

        //Bind with the second select list
        public List<int> SelectedId2 { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model SomeViewModel

<form asp-action="DropDown" method="post">
    <select asp-for="SelectedId1" asp-items="@ViewBag.City1">
        
    </select>

    <select asp-for="SelectedId2" asp-items="@ViewBag.City1">
        
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you simplify with using my model.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer,please check it

Comment: Okay.  My list contain id as int and text as a string . so please explain how can i apply  x.Selected = true to that list.

Comment: I've updated my answer again,hopes could help